# Actions is not performed even tho the line is called earlier

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress

There is a form that dont fit fully to a screen so i need to scroll up to actually click on the text(link - href) however when i am doing cy.get(href) screen get stuck even tho the cy.get called after cy.scrollTo()  , so it fails with error that another element on the way but which is weird cy scrollTo should perform first moving upwards then the cy.get(href) but it gets stuck

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNqoV.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The error says there is another element covering the one you are attempting to click. You can either click on the covering element, update your click to `cy.get(href).click({force:true})`, or make changes on the dev side.

Comment: the weird thing is  that cy.get() is called after the cy.scrollTo(top)  and it works if i dont have cy.get after  it however if i do have it does not go up and then cy.get complains that there is an element

Comment: man that worked and honestly i have no idea how it did worked as if its says there is something on the way  why would force click work

Comment: Forcing the click isn't always the best method. Alternatively to using `.scrollTo(top)` you can do `cy.get().scrollIntoView()`  and that will scroll whatever element you queried into view window.